# How to Convert a list of objects to a string list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Person objects

```
class Person
{
    string FirstName{get;set;}
    int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Now in this Person objects list

Person1 has FirstName="Alan", Age=20

Person 2 has FirstName="Josephine", Age=21

I need to get a new List, where each list item has the first name concatenated with the age

**List I need:**

Alan:20

Josephine:21

...so on

I have this so far...

```
var PersonConcatenatedList= from p in PersonList
                            select new {firstName= p.FirstName, Age=p.Age};
```

err...but now how to ouput the desired list format ? :(

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string.Join`:

```
var PersonConcatenatedList = PersonList
                            .Select(x => string.Join(":", x.FirstName, x.Age));
```

Since you need a list of strings you shouldn't create ananymous types.Simple string concatanation would also work:

```
PersonList.Select(x => x.FirstName + ":" + x.Age));
```

If you want output as a *single* string, then use `string.Join` via `Environment.NewLine` and concatanate the results with new line character:

```
var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, PersonConcatenatedList);
```

Comment: The result will be a collection, so you can format the new line after each iteration in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is one way to go. But for good programming I suggest implementing the [`.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173154.aspx) method.

```
class Person
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.FirstName + ":" + this.Age;
    }
}
```

Then simply use the following:

```
var result = personList.Select(person => person.ToString());
```